# Jira - JQL query to identify a status change only

Tags: jira, webhooks, jql

While creating a web hook in Jira I can't seem to find the best way to trigger it when the status of the web hook was updated.

```
status changed FROM "Development" TO "Development Review"
```

The problem is that any time a user modifies anything from the description to the assignee, the web hook gets triggered.

I've set this web hook to only trigger during a transition change from Development to Development Review, however this seems to "activate" the web hook and not necessarily trigger it for a moment.

How can JQL be formatted in a way to only work for a status change?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

status was "Development" and status = "Development Review"

Comment: That won't work. The `was` keyword verifies if at any point in time the status was "Development" which would always return true in this case

Answer (score 0):

Do not use JQL in the webhook configuration. Simply create the webhook (with no events enabled) and just call this webhook directly from the workflow as post-function (trigger webhook postfunction).

See [Atlassian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/advanced-workflow-configuration-938847443.html#Advancedworkflowconfiguration-optionalpostfunctionsOptionalpostfunctions).